# Retrieve next value of Oracle sequence via stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, sequence

I have created a SEQUENCE in Oracle11g which is working as expected. The challenge is that I need to retrieve the next value of the sequence via a stored procedure (because the application I'm using can only call a stored procedure not a sql statement).

I have looked all over and the closest I've found is this (here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2216649):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CSDWH.CSDWH_RETURN_SEQ_NUM 
(SEQ_NAME IN VARCHAR2,SEQUENCE_OUT OUT NUMBER) 
IS 
BEGIN   
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || SEQ_NAME || '.NEXTVAL from dual' INTO sequence_out; 
END;
```

The issue with this is the way of execution:

```
declare
  l_val number;
begin
  csdwh_return_seq_num( 'FOO_SEQ', l_val );
  dbms_output.put_line( l_val );
end;
```

The application I need to execute the stored procedure only have a connection string alias, a stored procedure name, and a return parameter field to be specified. The way to execute this stored procedure required 6 lines of code.

Is there any way to achieve the above with the EXECUTE command?

```
i.e. EXECUTE CSDWH.CSDWH_RETURN_SEQ_NUM
```

that would return the value?

Comment: You are not going to get a better answer than Justin Cave gave you.  I don't know why he recommended the use of execute immediate rather than select into.  What is the problem with using a function as he recommends?

Comment: `execute` is a SQL*Plus command.  Are you really using SQL*Plus (or a tool that emulates some subset of SQL*Plus commands) to execute your procedure?  A stored procedure does not return anything (though, as you've seen, it can have OUT parameters).  A stored function does return something which is why the original suggestion was to use a function instead.  Whether your tool can call a function directly without putting it in a SQL statement is hard to guess.

Answer (score 0):

just create a function instead of procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_SEQ(SEQ_NAME IN VAECHAR2) AS
DECLARE
    seq_out NUMBER;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || SEQ_NAME || '.NEXTVAL from dual' INTO seq_out;
    RETURN seq_out;
END;
```

then you can use `select get_seq('foo_seq') from dual`